# Redux Reducer => Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, redux-form

so I have a pretty odd error and I'm not sure why or how to fixit.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

so what is wrong in here? I have tried to add the default state directly into the reducer how I saw other answers regarding this error but didn't worked for me.

Action:

```
export const createProfile = profileValues => async dispatch => {
  const response = await profileApi.post('/profileApi', profileValues);

  dispatch({ type: CREATE_PROFILE, payload: response.data });
};
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    values: {}
  };
  
  export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case CREATE_PROFILE:
        return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

Component:

```
const Profile = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => (props.createProfile()))

    return (
        'Return'
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { profile: Object.values(state.profile) };
  };
  
  export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { createProfile }
  )(Profile);
```

Comment: It would be useful to know at which line that exception is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.values()` can't convert `null` or `undefined` to an object with properties it can extract.

Before the API returns, the `mapStateToProps` selector tries to get the values of `state.profile`, which is `undefined`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { profile: Object.values(state.profile) };
};
```

Set the initial value of the `profile` as an empty object:

```
const initialState = {
  values: {
    profile: {}
  }
};
```

Or use a fallback value - `{}` at the selector's level:

```
return { profile: Object.values(state.profile ?? {}) };
```

Comment: thank you, you're right, the return of mapStateToProps was the problem.